# Passing information between classes in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a basic app in Kivy with a class for each screen. I would like to have the user enter some text in one screen and for this to be displayed in a label on another screen.

I've been through all the similar posts but can't seem to get anything working.

The two classes EnterSentences and Review have ObjectProperties. Is there a way to connect these with bind? Or do I need to just structure things completely differently?

Any help much appreciated. Here's the .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):

    def enter_sentences_button(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(EnterSentences())

    def review_button(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(Review())

    def settings_button(self):
        pass


class EnterSentences(BoxLayout):
    search_box = ObjectProperty()
    def main_menu(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(MainMenu())


class Review(BoxLayout):
    sentence = ObjectProperty()

class NewApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    NewApp().run()
```

and the .kv file:

```
MainMenu

<MainMenu>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: "Welcome to your Flash Card App!"
        size_hint_y: 5
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 1
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Button:
            text: "Enter sentences"
            on_press: root.enter_sentences_button()
        Button:
            text: "Review"
            on_press: root.review_button()
        Button:
            text: "Settings"


<EnterSentences>:
    search_box: enter_sentence
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "Enter your sentences here:"
        size_hint_y: 4
    TextInput:
        id: enter_sentence
    TextInput:
    TextInput:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: 'Main Menu'
            on_press: root.main_menu()
        Label:
            text: ''


<Review>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        size_hint_y: 4
        text: root.search_box
    TextInput:
        size_hint_y: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change the kv file. You could add the text from the 3 TextInputs to 3 variables readable from the whole app:

```
      TextInput:
+         on_text: app.sentence1=self.text
          id: enter_sentence
      TextInput:
+         on_text: app.sentence2=self.text
      TextInput:
+         on_text: app.sentence3=self.text
```

Then you could access the new variables in the Review:

```
<Review>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        size_hint_y: 4
        text: app.sentence1 + "\n" + app.sentence2 + "\n" + app.sentence3
    TextInput:
        size_hint_y: 1
```